# Gradle Crittercism on-build mapping upload not working

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, crittercism

I'm trying to upload to Crittercism on build, and I put this at the bottom of my gradle file. However, it doesn't seem to be working when I build debug. What am I doing wrong?

```
task uploadMappingToProd() << {
    def critterAppId = "abcde"
    def appVersionName = "1.0.1"
    def appVersionCode = "DEBUG"
    def critterKey = "12345"

    commandLine 'curl',
            "https://app.crittercism.com/api_beta/proguard/$critterAppId",
            '-F', 'proguard=@build/outputs/mapping/production/release/mapping.txt',
            '-F', "app_version=$appVersionName-$appVersionCode",
            '-F', "key=$critterKey"

    type Exec
    dependsOn 'assembleDebug'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've done it, the task that you have defined, `uploadMappingToProd`, will *if invoked* by some reason also invoke `assembleDebug`. Because you have asked `uploadMappingToProd` to depend on `assembleDebug` - not the reverse. Therefore `assembleDebug` will happily finish without getting anywhere close to `uploadMappingToProd`.

If you want the reverse dependency i.e. `assembleDebug` to depend on `uploadMappingToProd` then you need to add this line after defining your task.

```
afterEvaluate {       
    tasks.assembleDebug.dependsOn uploadMappingToProd
}
```

This will guarantee `uploadMappingToProd` is invoked *everytime* and *before* `assembleDebug` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is working fine.(local build and jenkins build)

for me, only working when build is from jenkins

make sure your APPID, APPKEY, and path(release_jenkins.... normally release)

**build.gradle (app)** (add at the end)

```
task uploadPro << {
    logger.error("Uploading mapping.txt file to crittercism")
    String temp = projectDir;
    temp = temp.replace("\\", "/");
    String[] cmd = ["curl", "-k", "https://app.crittercism.com/api_beta/proguard/AppIDSting",
                 "-F", "proguard=@" + temp + "/build/outputs/mapping/release_jenkins/mapping.txt",
                 "-F", "app_version=" + VERSION_NAME + '-' + VERSION_CODE,
                 "-F", "key=API_KEY"]
    logger.error("CMD : " + cmd)
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    Process process = builder.start();
    process.waitFor()
    println process.err.text
    println process.text
    }

gradle.buildFinished {
    //check your build type. I am not sure it's the best way to do it.
    logger.error("JSC : 이름 ! - " + gradle.startParameter.taskNames);
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("assembleRelease_jenkins")) {
        logger.error("JSC : 올리기 시작 ! - " + gradle.startParameter.taskNames);
        tasks.uploadPro.execute()
    } else {
        logger.error("JSC : PASS")
    }
}
```

sample project -> https://github.com/SinsangMarket/CrittercismMappingTXT